# Concurrent updates on the same table from different servers for different records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

As far I read from this forum, its understood that there may not be any issue in a design like this. But wanted to be in the safe side.

I have a simple update query as below which has to be executed in a server (Lets say Master server):

```
update TempTable set [TempCol_1] = 'Value_1' 
where TempTable.[ TempCol_2] = ‘Server_1’
```

The **'Value_1'** and **'Server_1’** are variable fields. This same query has to be run from different servers.
For example, when this query is being executed from ‘server-1’ , **where TempTable.[ TempCol_2] = ‘Server_1’**
when this query is being executed from ‘server-2’
**where TempTable.[ TempCol_2] = ‘Server_2’** and so on.

It means, even if there are concurrent updates on the same table in the master server, the where condition will remain different for each server and from each server, **at a given time**, there will be only one execution of the query.

While designing this scenario, should we be worried about table locks or any other lock/transaction issue on the table in the master server (i.e TempTable) ??  Will the table be open to update at the same time from different servers or will it wait for the first triggered updation to complete and makes the second triggered updation is some sort of queue or somethng??

Comment: (Syntax is clearly SQL Server, so I removed the mysql tag).  I don't understand your question.  Temporary tables are local to a server, so the updates would go in separate tables, on separate servers.